# In IICS, CAI, are you allowed to unpublish a parent asset that contains another asset?

Tags: dependencies, informatica

My understanding is that in IICS, CAI, it is necessary to unpublish and delete dependent assets prior to unpublishing and deleting the assets they depend on. At the same time, IICS seems to indicate that the following statement is true: "In CAI, it is not allowed to unpublish a parent asset that contains another asset." How is this possibly true? It seems to contradict the necessity of deleting dependent assets prior to the assets they depend upon.